# How to add missing mobile hotspot quick setting toggle on MIUI second space?

Tags: miui, quick-settings

Recently I noticed the second space in MIUI has been stripped of several handy settings and shortcuts, which is a back draw on an otherwise good feature.

I am looking for a way to add missing shortcuts on quick setting panel (without necessarily installing 3rd party application(s)). I already have a shortcut to the required setting i.e mobile hotspot, but I prefer a quick setting tile.

I want to achieve something similar to this: [How to Restore the Mobile Data and Mobile Hotspot Quick Settings Toggles on Samsung Galaxy Devices](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-restore-mobile-data-quick-settings-tile-toggle-on-samsung-galaxy-devices/) but in this case for MIUI second space.

Note: `settings get secure sysui_qs_tiles` already has entry for hotspot tile, but it just doesn't appear in second space.

*Automation solution is appreciated but should be toggle option on quick settings*

The device is rooted, running on Android 9 miui.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using an app that enables Wi-Fi directly from the second space. I use "Mobile Hotspot".
However, surely the programming expert knows how to display the native tool in the second space just using an editor like Setedit. I would also like to know how..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).